# Complex integral with Cauchy integral formula

Tags: complex-analysis

For $k>1$ integer i want to compute the integral $$\int_0^{\infty}e^{-t^k}dt $$

by using Cauchy's integral formula.

Edit: The actual integral im trying to solve is $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\int_0^{x}e^{it^k}dt$$

but apparantly this is equal to $$e^{\pi i/2k}\int_0^{\infty}e^{-t^k}dt$$

Comment: *Cauchy, please.

Comment: haha :D An admirer of mr. Cauchy.  Here I changed it. Happy?

Comment: Not really sure what Cauchy is going to buy you unless you plan on integrating something like $e^{i t^k}$.

Comment: well that is funny you say that cause the actual integral I want to solve is $\lim_{x\to\infty}\int_0^x e^{it^k}dt$

Comment: But some excercise says that this is equal to $e^{\pi i /2k}\int_0^{\infty}e^{t^k}dt$ but i dont even understand this...that's why im trying to solve the other integral.So maybe i should change the question.

Comment: I meant $e^{\pi i /2k}\int_0^{\infty}e^{-t^k}dt$

Comment: I think the point of the exercise is to show that 
$\int_0^\infty e^{it^k}\ dt = e^{\pi i/(2 k)} \int_0^\infty e^{-t^k}\ dt$ using a wedge-shaped contour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the change of variables $t = s^{1/k}$; do you know the $\Gamma$ function?

Comment: I have seen it why?

Comment: If you know the definition of this function as an integral, there's your answer.

Comment: That looks like a smart idea...so $\Gamma(1)= \int_0^{\infty}e^{-t}dt$. But dont you mean the substitution $s= t^k$?

Comment: Hmm...I think this will help me out. Thnx.

Comment: So the answer is $k\Gamma(k)$ I guess...

Comment: and according to Wikipedia this is...$k!$ This is such a weird function then.

Answer (score 0):

Begin by letting $$u=t^k \iff u^{\frac{1}{k}}=t \iff \frac{1}{k}u^{\frac{1}{k}-1}du=dt$$
yielding the integral:$$\frac{1}{k}\int_0^{\infty} u^{\frac{1}{k}-1}e^{-u}$$
Remembering that $$\Gamma(z)=\int_0^\infty x^{z-1}e^{-x}dx$$
We can see that our original integral is then nothing but$$\frac{1}{k}\Gamma(\frac{1}{k})$$

Comment: Your answer adds nothing new to the answer that was accepted more than five years ago.